# 2 classes in 2 header files

Tags: c++, class, header-files

I am trying to compile a program that has 2 .h and 3.cpp . I keep getting the same error message: "error: ‘Patrons’ does not name a type   Patrons match;"

when I put the whole code in one single .cpp file, I have no errors and it compiles, but for my assignment I need to do it in separate files.

I think I wrote the code right so I dont know why I get the error message.

```
// class patrons.h

using namespace std;

class Patrons //named it patrons because this is where i have a list of all    the patrons
{   

    int patronscnt;
    public:
    std::list<string>::iterator PL;
    std::list<string> patslist;
    string name;
    void patronslist();
    void addpatron();
    void removepatron();
    void editpatron();

};
```

-

```
// class patron.h

using namespace std;

class Patron //class decleration. Named it patron because it has the information of one patron
{
    string x;
    string input;//class members
    Patrons match;
    public:

    void ID();
    void email();
    void phone();
    void address();
    void borrowstatus();
    void finestatus();
    void check(string);
    //update
 };
```

Comment: This has odd naming. Why would the singular `Patron` contain the plural `Patrons`? A casual reader will expect the opposite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could include patrons.h in patron.h.

You accomplish this by adding the following to the top of the patron.h file:

```
#include "patrons.h"
```

However in my opinion, it is generally better to store a pointer to an object instead of the entire object. If you were to switch the match variable in patron.h to be a Patrons pointer:

```
Patrons *match;
```

Then instead of including patrons.h, you could forward declare the Patrons class, by adding the following to the top of the patron.h file:

```
class Patrons;
```

Then if needed you could include patrons.h in your patron.cpp file. Forward declaring will help you from running into circular dependencies.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to make it compile.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include Patrons.h in Patrons: `#include "Patrons.h"`